# RAG calculations in a separate table then used in a materialized view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postegres and have three tables one with metric results, one with additional fields per metric. Finally one that contains the calculations to get the RAG status for each metric based on the threshold values.

What I aim to achieve is a materialized view that will automatically updated based on triggers. This view will have all the results by month with relevant additional fields and applicable RAG calculation using the thresholds and calcs table.

Tried various approaches though not had success...

Scripts:

```
--Create the results table
CREATE TABLE tbl_results (
    uid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    kid VARCHAR(50) not null,
    dte DATE  not null,
    res numeric (18,4) NULL,
    res_v numeric (18,4) NULL,
    dte_added DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE not null,
    bsn VARCHAR(50) null,
    constraint pk_results unique (uid)
);

--Insert into results table
INSERT INTO tbl_results
(uid, kid, dte, res, res_v, dte_added, bsn)
VALUES(1, 'IN1', '2023-12-31', 1.2587, 2.665, CURRENT_DATE, '');
VALUES(2, 'IN2', '2023-12-31', 2.15, .225, CURRENT_DATE, '');
VALUES(3, 'IN3', '2023-12-31', 3.856, 1.9, CURRENT_DATE, '');
VALUES(4, 'IN4', '2023-12-31', 1.978, 6.9, CURRENT_DATE, '');
VALUES(5, 'IN5', '2023-12-31', 45.69, 7855, CURRENT_DATE, '');

--Create the ki table
CREATE TABLE tbl_ki (
    kid VARCHAR(50) not null,
    ki_nme varchar(100) not null,
    ki_desc varchar(150) not null,
    ki_purp varchar (150) not null,
    ki_req varchar (150) not null,
    ki_own varchar (150) not null,
    ki_jrny varchar (150) not null,
    calc_id varchar (10) not null,
    threshold_red float not null,
    threshold_amber float not null
);

INSERT INTO tbl_ki (kid, ki_nme, ki_desc, ki_purp, ki_req, ki_own, ki_jrny, calc_id, threshold_red, threshold_amber) VALUES
('IN1', 'Knowledge Base System', 'A system for storing and retrieving knowledge articles', 'To provide users with a centralized repository for accessing information', 'Database management system, Web server, User interface', 'IT department', 'Requirements gathering, Development, Testing, Deployment', 'CALCID001', 0.8, 0.6),
('IN2', 'Inventory Management System', 'A system for tracking and managing inventory levels', 'To optimize stock levels and streamline inventory processes', 'Database management system, Barcode scanners, User interface', 'Warehouse manager', 'Requirements analysis, Design, Implementation, Maintenance', 'CALCID002', 0.9, 0.7),
('IN3', 'Customer Relationship Management System', 'A system for managing interactions with customers', 'To improve customer service and increase sales efficiency', 'Database management system, Email integration, Customer portal', 'Sales team', 'Lead generation, Sales process management, Customer support', 'CALCID003', 0.85, 0.65)

--Create the calcs table
CREATE TABLE tbl_calcs (
    calc_id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    calc text not null,
    dte_added DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE not null
);

INSERT INTO tbl_calcs (calc_id, calc) VALUES
('CALCID001', 'CASE WHEN res < threshold_red THEN 3 ELSE 1 END'),
('CALCID002', 'CASE WHEN res > threshold_amber THEN 1 WHEN res > threshold_red AND res <= threshold_amber THEN 2 ELSE 3 END'),
('CALCID003', 'CASE WHEN res >= threshold_red THEN 3 WHEN res > threshold_amber THEN 2 ELSE 1 END')
```

Comment: `Tried various approaches though not had success...` What have you tried?

Comment: Postgres does not have an updateable materialized view; materialized views are only modified via the [refresh materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) statement. This could be run as a dynamic sql from a trigger but that could be a very expensive (slow) process. At a minimum you need to post the `create materialized view ...`  with the creation query.